# Connecting 2 different discord channels with one another

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord, discord.js

So I am making a bot with JavaScript and wanted to know how to link a channel from a different server to another channel from a different server, The only thing is that I don't know exactly how to do such a thing, I know that I have to link channels in the database but still have no idea.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "connect" and "link"?

Comment: I am trying to make a bot that connects 2 channels from different servers with one another and facing a problem with doing so, I am not asking for code, I am just asking for an explanation on how to do it, Since I tried researching on it but couldn't find any relevant explanation